# Knowing Deleted Documents in Couchbase lite android

Tags: android, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I am using Couchbase lite 1.0 beta2 to get and replicate data from couchbase server. In My case, If a document is deleted from server, I am unable to check it in android app whether a document already present locally is deleted from server. In the replicator method, it only returns me the changed documents or newly added documents.

I tried with "document.isDeleted()" but it always returns false.

So, How can I put a check whether a document is deleted from server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A deleted document uses the special property `_deleted: true` to indicate a tombstoned document.  So it's possible to build a view to index these documents.  It's important that you are specifically using this property and not simply deleting the document.

Here is what the couchbase documentation says on tombstoning:

> Tombstoning
>
> The reason that tombstone revisions exist is so that deletes can be
>   sync'd to other databases. If revisions were simply deleted with a
>   naive approach, then there would be no easy way to sync up with other
>   databases that contained the revision.

[Couchbase Lite docs](http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/revision/index.html#Tombstoning)

Comment: https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.5/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/revision/index.html#tombstones